# Laravel 5.2 Application crashes after adding to database

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 to create an events table on a website . The table is added to by a form . When I click the add button to submit the form to the database I get this error "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:" but the data is still added to the database on phpmyadmin.
Here is the code :

```
Page Controller Code :
 public function save_new_event()
{
    $input = Request::all();

    App\Event::create($input);

    return redirect('pages.events');
}

Routes code:

Route::get('/events', 'PageController@events');

Route::post('/events', 'PageController@save_new_event');
```

I'm not sure what other code I  should include here but I can upload more if it will help. I can't find out what cause the page to crash and apologise if its something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
return redirect('pages.events');
```

To this:

```
return redirect()->route('events');
```

Or you can use:

```
return redirect('/events');
```

With `redirect('pages.events');` you're trying to refirect to this URL: `/pages.events` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you ! This has stopped the page crashing . Could you explain why ? I thought that as the events view was in the pages file I had to include it as i did ?

Comment: Sure. You need to redirect to URL with `redirect()` or to route with 'redirect->route()'. You're trying to redirect to URL `/pages.events` which doesn't exist, that's why you're getting error.

Comment: It's `redirect()->route('events')`.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense ! @AlexeyMezenin